# onblur called if checkbox value changes, how to prevent that?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lightning component with lightning-input type checkbox and formatted-text.

By default formatted-text shown,

1. If double click the formatted-text, it is hide and lightning-input
   shown.
2. If blur the lightning-input, it is hide and formatted-text
   shown.

The problem was, if checkbox value changed onblur called, so each time checkbox value changed, the formatted-text shown. How to fix this?

I need to hide the checkbox it is blur only, don't hide it value change.

[playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/QtUFE9Zat/9/edit)

js file

```
export default class App extends LightningElement {
    isRendered = false;
    mode = 'VIEW';
    value = true;

    get isEditMode() {
        return this.mode === 'EDIT';
    }

    get isViewMode() {
        return this.mode === 'VIEW';
    }

    handleOnChange(event) {
        console.log('on_change');
        this.value = event.target.checked;
    }

    handleOnBlur(event) {
        console.log('on_blur');
        this.mode = 'VIEW';
    }

    handleOnDblClick() {
        this.mode = 'EDIT';
    }
}
```

html file

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isViewMode}>
        <div ondblclick={handleOnDblClick}>{value}</div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={isEditMode}>
        <lightning-input type="checkbox"
            label=" "
            checked={value}
            onchange={handleOnChange}
            onblur={handleOnBlur}>
        </lightning-input>
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to enable and disable blur logically. Have a boolean to set to true and false depending on where the mouse is.

html:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isViewMode}>
        <div ondblclick={handleOnDblClick}>{value}</div>
    </template>
    <template if:true={isEditMode}>
        <div onmouseenter={handleMouseEnter} onmouseleave={handleMouseLeave}>
            <lightning-input type="checkbox"
                            label=" "
                            checked={value}
                            onchange={handleOnChange}
                            onblur={handleOnBlur}>
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
handleMouseEnter() {
    console.log('handleMouseEnter');
    this._processBlur = false;
}

handleMouseLeave() {
    console.log('handleMouseEnter');
    this._processBlur = true;
}

handleOnBlur(event) {
    if(this._processBlur) {
        console.log('on_blur');
        this.mode = 'VIEW';
    }
}
```

#### Note:

Instead of double click and blur events, you can probably think about achieving same thing via `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. On `mouseenter`, show editable mode and on `mouseleave`, show readable mode.

[playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/QtUFE9Zat/14/edit)

Comment: It is working fine me, Thank you.